# Spring's Security ReactiveAuthenticationManager doesn't handle Redis async calls to check token revocation

Tags: spring-security, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have the following easy implementation of ReactiveAuthenticationManager (I found it via an online
Reactive Spring Security tutorial):

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String authToken = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    try {
        if (!jwtUtil.validateToken(authToken, true)) {
            return empty();
        }
        Claims claims = jwtUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(authToken, true);
        return just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(claims.getSubject(), null));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return empty();
    }
}
```

This works properly, but if I use the following version to check via an async Redis call if the token is revocated, Spring doesn't execute the call in the proper order and jumps directly to the RestController.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String authToken = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    try {
        if (!jwtUtil.validateToken(authToken, true)) {
            return empty();
        }
        Claims claims = jwtUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(authToken, true);
        return reactiveTemplate.opsForZSet().score("nameOfTheSortedSet", authToken)
                .flatMap(score -> score > 0 ? empty() : just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(claims.getSubject(), null, authorities)))
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return empty();
    }
}
```

My theory is that the call is actually executed, but too late, after the business logic from either a controller or service is executed.

Comment: What do you mean is not executed in proper order? If you mean that its never goes to flatMap?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat That's correct. It reaches the authentication manager (it enters in a breakpoint set on the return statement) but goes directly to the rest controller, skipping the extra authentication rules found in flatMap.